# Replacing optimoptions with optimset in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

My MATLAB doesn't support **`optimoptions`**.

How can I rewrite the following routine using **`optimset`** so that it produces the same exact result?

```
options = optimoptions('fminunc','Display','off','OutputFcn',
                        @bananaout,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
[x,fval,eflag,output] = fminunc(fun,x0,options);
title 'Rosenbrock solution via fminunc'
Fcount = output.funcCount;
disp(['Number of function evaluations for fminunc was ',num2str(Fcount)])
disp(['Number of solver iterations for fminunc was ',num2str(output.iterations)])
```

Comment: Doesn't `optimset('Display','off','OutputFcn', @bananaout,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');` work for you?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama, no it generates Error.`??? Error using ==> optimset at 223
Invalid value for OPTIONS parameter Algorithm:
 must be 'active-set', 'trust-region-reflective', 'interior-point', 'interior-point-convex',
 'levenberg-marquardt', 'trust-region-dogleg', 'lm-line-search', or 'sqp'.`

Comment: This indicates that you cannot use quasi-newton algorithm, so use one from the available options, no?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama, I actually need to use Quasi-Newton for my project. It is specific.

Comment: then may be you'd have to write it yourself as clearly it is not available with `optimset` or upgrade to a newer version of MATLAB to be able to use `optimoptions`

Comment: @Sardar_Usama, Hmmm.........